# Statistics Help: Difference between Differences?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, contrasts

I don't know that this is really the right forum to be asking this, but I'm hoping for some statistics help.

I have 4 conditions: A, B, C, D. I'm looking to determine whether the difference between A and B is significantly different than the difference between C and D. The conditions aren't paired (e.g. A and B aren't paired, C and D aren't paired). Does anyone have suggestions for which statistical tests to run?

**Example data in R:**

```
structure(list(A = c(32L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 31L), 
    B = c(33L, 35L, 36L, 32L, 35L, 37L), C = c(33L, 
    28L, 31L, 32L, 29L, 27L), D = c(42L, 45L, 38L, 49L, 
    47L, 48L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Specifically, do you want to look at a - b vs c - d? By "aren't paired," do you mean that there are just 4 separate random variables that just happen to have the same length? Is there any meaning to the rows (time, selection order, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, “a-b” vs “c-d.” The rows have no meaning. By “aren’t paired” I just mean that, for example, column A row 2 is not in any way connected to column B row 2. The columns just happen to have the same length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a little risky to answer without better understanding your use case, but assuming iid nested data within columns and testing the hypotheses:

$$
H_0: \mu_A - \mu_B = \mu_C - \mu_D, \\
H_1: \mu_A - \mu_B \ne \mu_C - \mu_D,
$$
you could appeal to the central limit theorem and construct a Wald test, comparing
$$
Z = \frac{(\bar{x_A} - \bar{x_B}) - (\bar{x_C} - \bar{x_D})}{\sqrt{s_A^2/n_A +s_B^2/n_B +s_C^2/n_C +s_D^2/n_D}}
$$
to a $N(0, 1)$ distribution (i.e., is $|Z| > 1.96$ for $\alpha=.05$.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!